# What is the difference between a GPG signature and a detached signature?

Tags: gpg, signature

We can sign a file with `gpgp`:

```
gpg -s file.pdf
```

Which generates a file signature `file.pdf.gpg`.

It is also possible to make a detached signature:

```
gpg -b file.pdf
```

Which generates `file.pdf.sig`.

I noticed that the `*.sig` files are always 566 bytes, while the size of `*.gpg` is proportional to the size of the original file.

My questions are:

- What is the difference between a GPG signature and a detached signature?
- Why are `*.gpg` signatures larger?
- Is one more secure than the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is the difference between a GPG signature and a detached signature?

By "GPG signature" you mean a signed message. This is the data being signed and the signature combined into one file. In contrast, a detached signature is separate from the file being signed.

> Why are *.gpg signatures larger?

Because it includes a compressed copy of the file that is being signed along with the signature data, whereas a detached signature is the signature data only.

> Is one more secure than the other?

The signatures are calculated in the exact same way for both formats.

For anything other than small text files it is usually easier to use a detached signature.

Answer (score 2):

With -s, the output is the *original document including the signature*, in other words the output is the signed document. That explains why its size varies with the document size.

With -b, the output is the *signature alone*. You then have two files, the signature and the original unchanged document.

Which one you choose is a question of workflow and convenience. For example, if you don't want to bother peeling the original document from the `.gpg` file, create a detached signature instead. However, you then must ensure that the signature file and the document file are kept together.

The same algorithms are used to create the signature in both cases. Therefore, I don't see that one is more secure than the other.

See the [manual](https://www.gnupg.org/gph/en/manual/x135.html):

> The command-line option --sign is used to make a digital signature. The document to sign is input, and **the signed document is output**.